# Корекктное правило в urlrewrite

Tags: битрикс, чпу

Имеется ссылка

```
mysite.ru/catalog/dlya-nee/obuv/?designer=ALOHAS
```

которая фильтрует раздел /dlya-nee/obuv/ по параметру ?designer=...
На выходе должны получить

```
mysite.ru/catalog/dlya-nee/obuv/designer/alohas/
```

Обрабатываю в urlrewrite ее так:

```
array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/catalog/(.*?)/designer/([a-zA-Z/-]+)/#',
    'RULE' => '/catalog/$1/?designer=$2',
    'SORT' => 10,
 )
```

Но получается так что выводит на страницу все разделы, как корректно составить правило чтобы отображало только то, что расположено в /catalog/dlya-nee/obuv/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось всё просто.

1. В urlrewrite.php добавил правило

   array (
   'CONDITION' => '#^/catalog/(.*?)/designer/([a-zA-Z/-]+)/#',
   'RULE' => 'designer=$2',
   'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
   'PATH' => '/catalog/designer.php',
   'SORT' => 101,
   ),

Важно чтобы SORT был выше чем у правила для самого каталога.
Создал в директории каталога файл designer.php и продублировал в нем содержимое файла index.php.

Добавил в параметры компонента

```
"SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
....
'designer' => '#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/designer/#DESIGNER_NAME#/',
...
)
```

Создал в шаблоне компонента файл designer.php и продублировал в нем содержимое файла section.php.

Comment: ID показывает, какой компонент создал правило. Если не хочешь, чтобы твоё правило было неожиданно переписано битриксом, поставь 'ID'=>''

Answer (score 0):

Добавь на страницу, куда происходит переход, код:

```
<?
if ($USER->IsAdmin()) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $_SERVER['REAL_FILE_PATH'];
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Так ты увидишь, какой адрес формируется через urlrewrite. А то может оказаться, что срабатывает вовсе не то правило, которое ты ожидаешь.